# Halachos of an Aveil with Mishloach Manos

Tags: halacha, purim, mourning-aveilus, mishloach-manot

The Rama in [Orach Chaim 696:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95#.D7.95) says we do not send Misloach Manos to an Aveil (mourner). The way people send is to send it to the family, rather than directly to the Aveil.

1. If you do not know anyone else in the Aveil's family, can you still send it to such a family member?
2. Suppose someone is in Aveilus (mourning) and a person shows up delivering Mishloach Manos. How should he respond?

Answer (score 6):

Regarding sending to other family members even if you do not know them, see Shaalos UTshuvos Tshuvos VHanhogos Chelek 1 Siman 692:44, by Rabbi Moshe Sternbuch, which says that you can not give to other family members if you do not know them. However, Rabbi Dovid Feinstein (quoted by Rabbi Avrohom Aba Freundlich) has ruled that you may.

Regarding someone who shows up with Mishloach Manos to give to someone that is in mourning, the Shaarim Metzuyanim B'Halacha, Siman 143:12, says in the name of the Ksav Sofer that the Aveil may accept it.